# How to access NSMutableArray given an object in it

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

If I am given an object that I know is in an `NSMutableArray`, how can I access that `NSMutableArray` and the index of the object in that `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: `int idx = [array indexOfObject:theObject];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly.     You would, at least, need references to all possible arrays the object might be in.   With that, you could ask each for objectAtIndex:.   If the return value is not NSNotFound, the object is in the array.

Of course, that is potentially slow and a sign of bad design.

One solution would be to have a reference from your object to the array.   This will work, but you need to makes sure the circular reference doesn't cause a leak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function indexOfObject:(id)object on the array and pass your object as the argument to receive the index.

For instance, let your array be NSMutableArray *array and the object be id obj.
Then, int index = [array indexObObject:obj];